# Do we need to create a bean in spring-cofig.xml if I use @Autowired Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

Do We need to write a bean in spring-config.xml if I use @Autowired? if yes why? I have this following example

```
@Controller
public class PasswordValidationController {

    private static final String ERRORS = "errors";
    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
    @Autowired
    PasswordValidatonServiceImpl passwordValidatorService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView passWordRequestPage() {
        return new ModelAndView(PASSWORD);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/validatepassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView passWordCheck(
            @ModelAttribute(PASSWORD) Password password, BindingResult result) {

        List<String> validate = passwordValidatorService.validatePassword(password
                .getPassword());

        if (!validate.isEmpty()) {
            return invalidPassword(validate);
        } else {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(SUCCESS);
            return model;
        }

    }

    private ModelAndView invalidPassword(List<String> validate) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(PASSWORD);
        model.addObject(ERRORS, validate);
        return model;
    }

}
```

Spring-config.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="passwordcheck.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/Jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

When I try to execute the above program I am getting below exception:

> ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [/passwordcheck].[password-check] -
>   Allocate exception for servlet password-check
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [passwordcheck.service.PasswordValidatonServiceImpl] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

If I add bean in spring-config xml I am able to resolve.

My question is do we need to write bean for my ServiceClass which is auto wired in my controller class?

Comment: My question is do we need to write bean in spring-config.xml for my ServiceClass which is auto wired in my controller class?

Comment: If you're trying to auto wire a bean, yes, you need a bean, otherwise you'll get the exception you see as the duplicate explains.

Comment: I found the solution, we don't need to write a bean in spring-config.xml if we specify the package as "<context:component-scan base-package="passwordcheck" />" and keep @Service annotation for service class.. any way thanks for the help..